# How to make ViewPager fullscreen?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager that I want to take the full-screen, but it only takes part of it. How can I make it take the full-screen? Here's my code, notice that it is filled with many calls to make the layout take the full-screen, to no avail.

walkthrough_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:minWidth="1080dp"
        android:minHeight="1920dp"/>       
    </RelativeLayout>
```

walkthrough_single_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

WalkthroughActivity.java:

```
package org.core.game.activities;

import org.core.game.Log;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;

public class WalkthroughActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final int MAX_VIEWS = 1;

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.walkthrough_activity);
        getWindow().setLayout(Main.screenWidth, Main.screenHeight);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new WalkthroughPagerAdapter());
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new WalkthroughPageChangeListener());
        mViewPager.setX(0);
        mViewPager.setY(0);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = width;

        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(width, height);
        mViewPager.setLayoutParams(lp);         
    }

    class WalkthroughPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return MAX_VIEWS;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
        {
            return view == (View) object;
        }

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position)
        {
            Log.e("instantiateItem(" + position + ");");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View imageViewContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.walkthrough_single_view, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageViewContainer.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;
            int height = width;
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1080, 1920);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1080, 1920);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.should_be_full_screen);
                    break;          
            }

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageViewContainer, 0);
            return imageViewContainer;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
        {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how it looks (the image is 1080*1920):

[image: And this is how it looks:]

**Edit:** I basically want to do a mini tutorial. One page with images, one page with a movie. What do you think is the best way?

Comment: Fullscreen? You might want to look into androids Immersive mode and save yourself all that layout params trouble. This devbyte might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBi8fjv90E4

Comment: How can I toggle between pages in Immersive Mode? I basically want to do a tutorial - one page with sample pictures, one page with a movie. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: The view pager should work normally when swiping through your two pages. All immersive mode does is hide the system bar and the system nav bar giving your content the full screen.

Comment: So I do need the View Pager :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so stupid... Notice that in my onCreate I have `getWindow().setLayout(Main.screenWidth, Main.screenHeight)` Annoyingly I made `Main.screenHeight)` to be 75 % :( Removing it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int deviceWidthInPixels = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int deviceHeightInPixels = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = deviceWidthInPixels;
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = deviceHeightInPixels;
```

Also, use this for `ViewPager`:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

And this for `ImageView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: try removing the `mViewPager.setLayoutParamter` code

Comment: also, remove the code from ViewPager class, from `Display display` to `imageView.setLayoutParamter`

Comment: I remove the .setLayoutParamter and it didn't help, and then I also removed setX and setY and that didn't help either

Comment: wow!! okay try `imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);`

Comment: oh, one simple technique to check problem is, change the background colours of `ImageView` and `ViewPager`, then see which thing goes upto where.

Comment: Still doesn't help. If I wrap ViewPager in red color for the background, I see that it spans the entire witdh, but not the entire high. about 15% up and down are black,

Comment: but the `ImageView` is taking whole `ViewPager`, correct ??

Comment: What do you mean? Simply see the code. I don't want to hide - if there is something missing tell me.

Comment: look, `ImageView` is on the `ViewPager`, which means, if `ViewPager`'s background colour is Red, and we cannot see red anywhere on screen, then it means that `ImageView` is covering whole `ViewPager`, and the problem is not with `ImageView` but with `ViewPager`. But if this is not the case, then problem is with `ImageView` and probably with `ViewPager` too.

Comment: See the answer I posted

Answer (score 0):

our code

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Change it to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Or you can try this adding to your ViewPager

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Let me know if further issue exists

-Now i saw your lines

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(width, height);
```

Change it to Below code:-
`Layoutparams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);`

Comment: But change your mainlayout height also match_parent

Comment: I changed in 2 xml's and in view_pager. If you want me to change a specific view/layout please tell me exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```